# Visible Scrollbar for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollbar

I know how to make `EditText` scrollable by setting

```
    e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    e.setScroller(new Scroller(AndroidExplorer.this)); 
    e.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
    e.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

but it's just showing a scrollbar.How can i Scroll Using that Scrollbar,How to accomplish that?

Now i can scroll by scrolling my edittext ,scrollbar also moves with that.But my need is to scroll using scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the following:

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"         //in XML
```

Or

```
e.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);    //in code
```

Comment: i Set another way including your code but the scrollbar is not working its just working with edittext

Comment: This crash my app with error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable.mutate()' on a null object reference`